# React setState twice renders state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When I trade with setState, it turns twice. First the Data Fail is returned and then the Data Ready is returned. Console return false first then true. I just want to return true in the console.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            data: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    data: result.data,
                    loading: true
                });
            });
    }
    render() {
        const { loading } = this.state;
        console.log(loading);
        const dataReady = <div>Data Ready </div>;

        const DataFail = <div>Data Fail </div>;
        return <div>{loading === true ? dataReady : DataFail}</div>;
    }
}
```

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kopz8wrl7o

Comment: What you mean by you want only return true?

Comment: yes only return true.

Comment: You mean like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/rj8po7jzrq

Comment: You can't just return true in the console. Because the initial state is false for loading. So that will show in the console before the initial render. After that, That will change to true.

Comment: You should look into the lifecyce function shouldComponentUpdate()

Comment: @EponymeWeb I do not see any reason to use this

Comment: @EponymeWeb I tried with shouldComponentUpdate but couldn't I do it.  Can you please show me through the sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply reversed the boolean associated with the loading. You should initially set it to `true` and then to `false` when your data is loaded.

Working example :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            error: false,
            data: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    data: result.data,
                    loading: false
                });
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                this.setState({ error: true });
            });
    }
    render() {
        const { loading, error } = this.state;
        !loading && console.log(true)

        return <div>{!loading && <div>Data Ready </div>}
          {error && <div>Data Error :( </div>}
        </div>;
    }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'/>
```

Comment: I guess I couldn't explain the question exactly. I just want to return true on the console, my initial value will be false.

Comment: You only want to return true when your data is loaded ?

Comment: Here you go, now your component logs `true` when your data is loaded

Comment: I need to perform the console process under render.

Comment: Alright, I have no idea with this is necessary but here you go. The condition to render anything that has finished loading is simply `!loading`

Comment: when you reload the page, data fail appears, then data ready appears. when you reload the page, I just want to return data ready.

Comment: You should have said that earlier, here you go, its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the React's lifecycle and the fact that you are setting the state.loading property initially to false. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

First there is the initial render, then the componentDidMount with its setState is called. You might want to leave the loading undefined and then in the render method check if its defined or not before checking its value.

Answer (score 0):

your data changes that's why you have two messages:
[image]

you need did decision, what's you gonna do?
if you didn't want change state you can use `shouldComponentUpdate`, or you can just skip 1 console  message

Comment: How can I do with shouldComponentUpdate without using componentDidMount ?

Comment: you can keep componentDidMount, and just add shouldComponentUpdate